# MySQL trigger to create and delete tables, make inserts and delete rows

Tags: mysql, triggers

**The Situation:**

So, on my website, I want to give users the opportunity to save complex sets of data from their excel tables. Since there will be a large number of users and limited resources, I don't want to store all the data in one single table.

My idea is to have tables where descriptive information is stored for the dataset the user wants to create. E.g.

Table: UserDatasets_sets
id, name, userid

Table: UserDatasets_columns
id, fk_UserDatasets_sets, name, type, length, etc...

And then at some place to run a mysql trigger that would

a) create a table of the name that is passed to be inserted with a certain prefix. E.g. 'UD_' + UserDatasets_sets.name and all the columns from the ..._columns table and an extra column fk_Acl.

b) Because I want to also give my users the opportunity to set permissions on the individual entries of their tables, I would then like to store a trigger for this newly created table. So that whenever a row is inserted, a corresponding row is created in the ACL table and the id is then set as the fk_Acl value on the user's table.

c) Last but not least, I would also like to store the same triggers in reverse, so that whenever a user deletes his dataset in the UserDatasets_sets table, the corresponding table gets deleted. The rest that is connected to this action could be deleted by cascading, right?

**My Question:**

Is this even possible to do as a trigger? (The reason why I would like to do this: I don't want to waste cpu and memory on running the more demanding php alternative.)

What would a query to store this trigger look like?